# Insert a date Object from json file in mongodb

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb

I have a JSON file with some data and want to add date information and then insert the content of this JSON file in mongoDB. The JSON file looks something like this:

```
[
    {
        "installationTime": "How do I insert a date Object here?",
        "someOtherValues": 0,
        ...
    },
    ...
]
```

And the insertion in node.js:

```
const content = await readFileAsync('pathToJSONfile.json');
// readFileAsync is fs.readFile wrapped in a promise
await db.createCollection('testCollection');
await db.collection('testCollection').insert(JSON.parse(content));
```

My question is: How do I insert a date Object like `ISODate("2016-12-18T18:30:00Z")` into the JSON file? Her in this forum I found:

`"installationTime": { "$date": "2016-12-18T18:30:00Z" }`

But then I get an Error from mongoDB `key $date must not start with '$'`.

Is my approach even possible with a json file and the insert command from the node driver?

Comment: JSON itself has no "types" so all data is either going to be a string or possibly numeric. What you read "in the forum" refers to [MongoDB Extended JSON](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json/) syntax. Now there are "some" libraries that exist which implement their own `.parse()` method which would accept dates formatted like that. Alternately you could use `mongoimport` instead, which supports that format. Or just use a plain ISOString, and either replace ( "parse" ) those strings as `Date` objects yourself, or even update enmasse once present in the collection.

Comment: So I'm not writing recommendations, but if I just search for [MongoDB Extended JSON](https://www.google.com/search?q=mongodb+extended+json), The top result is the official manual page, and shortly thereafter you might find things of interest to use in an application.

Answer (score 3):

I now have solved it like this:

Import of node module child_process ...

`import { exec } from 'child_process';`

... in order to execute shell commands.
And insertion of the JSON file with mongoimport:

```
exec('mongoimport --jsonArray --db tstdb --collection testCollection --file pathToJSONfile.json', (error) => {
  if (error) {
    console.log(`exec error: ${error}`);
  }
});
```

Then the `$date` key in the JSON file can be used for importing date objects:

```
"installationTime": { "$date": "2017-10-01T00:00:00.000Z" },
```

Now find() shows, that the date is stored as an ISODate Object:

```
> db.getCollection("feed_in_payments").find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("592bd66cb3395ba514bc1005"), "installationTime" : ISODate("2000-01-01T00:00:00Z"), ...
```

Comment: The key "$data" must start with "$" and the date string it must end with timezone, in this case "Z".